# ¿Cómo colocar el token al consumir una api privada con JavaScript mediante promesas?

Tags: javascript, html, api, autenticación, tokens

estoy iniciando en esto de las api y
Tengo que consumir una api que contiene una lista de credenciales, en la url de la misma ya contiene el .json/user_mail/user_token/y un filtro por fecha

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: como realizo la autenticación para que pueda imprimir los datos de esta api en una pagina usando js mediante promesas. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
const API = "aqui la url de la api";

const getData = (apiURL) => {
    return fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => { imDatos(json) })
    .catch(error => {console.error('Error: ', error) })
}


const imDatos = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(c => {
        html += '<div class="col"';
            html += '<div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">'
                html += '<img src="${c.image_url}" class="card-img-top">'
                html += '<div class="card-body">'
                    html += '<h5 class="card-title">${memorial_url}</h5>'

                html += '</div>'


            html += '</div>'
        html += '</div>'
    });
    document.getElementById('infoCharacters').innerHTML = html
}

getData(API);
```

aqui dejo el html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>api</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <div class="contenedor">
        <div id="infoCharacters"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="apic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Intente colocar en la contante "API" la url completa con los datos de acceso pero queda a la vista los datos de acceso.

Desde ya Gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de esto: "en la url de la misma ya contiene el .json/user_mail/user_token/y un filtro por fecha"? Pero pues obviamente no con los datos reales cambiados...
El problema que estás teniendo es que no sabes como enviar tu token de authenticación a esta API?

Comment: Hola, seria asi: https://api.dominio.group/valor.json?user_email=nombre@hotmail.com&user_token=GGGG1111TTTT222&q[starts_at_gteq]=2022-12-01
Esto me tira ya un json con toda la info necesaria para armar la grilla o credenciales. Logro hacer que la consola lo reconozca como tal, pero no logro imprimir los datos en el html (y el link del api queda a la vista de todos si entran a la consola). Gracias por tomarte el tiempo.

Comment: Según lo que entiendo lo que no quieres es que se vean las credenciales de acceso, pero si la petición es GET ahi no puedes hacer absolutamente nada, las peticiones GET admiten parámetros en la URL y siempre serán visibles. Ahí parece es más problema del diseño de la API. Eso de mandar el email y el token por la URL no es para nada recomendado. Tienes acceso al código de la API?

Comment: Claro entiendo, entonces no entiendo porque no puedo imprimirlo en el html, quizás mi problema sea otro, con el código que muestro no se imprimen los datos (pensé que era porque no me autorizaba a mostrarlos) Que estaré haciendo mal?
Y no, no tengo acceso al código de la API.

Comment: que te sale en la consola de "Red" (network)? si se ejecuta esa petición al servidor? si devuelve los datos que esperas?

Comment: Si si, me devuelve los datos en un json, luego lo trato de imprimir y en el html me sale un error de imagen y el texto plano asi: <https://prnt.sc/WDcpDzRcfQi9>